# Why does $.ready fire the jQuery document.ready event?

Tags: jquery, document-ready

We recently had a bug where the jquery document.ready seemed to be firing before the DOM loaded. It turned out that there was some errant code after the first item which was calling

`$.ready(function(){});`

It seemed that this statement was firing the document.ready event.

Here is a sample of the code:

```
<script>
    $(function(){
        alert("loaded");
    });
</script>
<ul>
    <li>  hello </li>
    <script>
        $.ready(function(){
    });
    </script>
    <li>  worldddd</li>
</ul>
```

And here is a jsfiddle where you can see the dom hasn't fully loaded when the alert get's executed.

http://jsfiddle.net/Kq78e/

My question is why does $.ready() fire the dom ready event? Is this a jquery "feature" which allows you to force the dom.ready event to fire?

Comment: yes. https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/1.9-stable/src/core.js#L397 it's an internal method that shouldn't be used outside of the core of jQuery unless you know what it does, why it does it, and have a good reason to use it. But, yes, it simply tells jQuery that the DOM is ready. This is the handler that is applied to the DOMContentLoaded event.

Comment: And if I'm not mistaken, the JQuery doc page also discourage the use of this : http://api.jquery.com/ready/

Comment: It discourages the use of `$().ready`, `$.ready` is never mentioned. I'd guess the only reason it's publicly available is so that it can be overridden if needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It fires the event because it is the handler for the event. http://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/1.9-stable/src/core.js#L397

it's an internal method that shouldn't be used outside of the core of jQuery unless you know what it does, why it does it, and have a good reason to use it.

It simply tells jQuery that the DOM is ready. This is the handler that is applied to the `DOMContentLoaded` event. Calling it yourself may result in the event happening too soon, as you have noticed. Most likely the usage in your code was meant to be this instead:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

});
```

Comment: yes by all means that is what it should have been. It's just that the "error" had unexpected consequences. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

`.ready()` runs as soon as the targeted object is ready. (Remember, `$` is an object and can be selected.)

When you specify `$.ready()`, you are telling the code to run as soon as jQuery (`$`) is loaded (as opposed to `$(document).ready()`, which runs when the document is loaded), which is why it runs before your DOM is loaded.

`$.ready()` is the equivalent of `$(document).on('ready', $, handler)`.

See the [`.ready()` documentation](http://api.jquery.com/ready/)